# Why are my resized images alway blurry?

Tags: node.js, sharp

I'm using node.js and sharp to resize images that my users upload. They are always blurry. I have no idea why. Here is my code:

```
var sharp = require("sharp");

sharp(file.path)
    .resize(width, height).max()
    .toFormat('png')
    .toBuffer(next);
    ...
```

Resized image is blurry. What am I missing?

By the way, I'm resizing larger images down to a smaller size. The `width` and `height` are proportional to the original size. For example, if the original dimension were 600x300, then the `width` and `height` are, for example, 300x150. So, it's definitely not an issue with miscalculating the width and height. I've also tried the same thing using imageMagick and had the same issues. I always get a resized image, but it's very blurry.

Comment: Are you scaling down by more than half? If you are, work in steps to half the size of the image until you're close to the final size, then perform a final step to complete your work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just did this and the images are still blurry, although they are less blurry than before.

Comment: Don't resize repeatedly. Sharp and IM already use a high-quality adaptive downsizer (lanczos3) --- repeated downsizing will reduce quality and be slower.

Comment: Can you give an example of bad output? If you just want your downsized image to "pop" a bit, try adding an extra `.sharpen()` step to the end of your pipeline: http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-operation/#sharpen

Answer (score 0):

With ImageMagick I found that using filter: "Catrom" https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-image-resize/v/0.13.1 and sharpen: "-1.5x1+0.7+0.02" http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize_unsharp works quite well when downsizing an image.